# Should I have brand search terms in separate ad group?

Tags: seo, keywords, google-ads

Scenario: Adwords campaign for Quality Management Software. I have set up Adwords groups for different aspects: QMS general, ISO 9001 QMS and 13485 QMS.

Should I set up additional groups for each of these, adapted each keyword to include the brand name? (where suitable)

Or should I simply put these branded versions of the keywords into each of the existing groups?

Answer (score 2):

I would say this depends on a few other aspects and is too much detail to go into on here.

To help you out, I have provided a couple of links below that should help. If these don't help, reply to this and I will see if I can better answer your question.

- [How do you structure your ad groups - via PPC Hero](https://www.ppchero.com/how-do-you-structure-your-ad-groups/)
- Based on what you are saying, you might also be interested in dynamic ads. [Dynamic search ads for beginners via PPC Hero](https://www.ppchero.com/dynamic-search-ads-for-beginners/)

Comment: I think I couldn't find the answer because rather than grouping brand terms in an ad group, I should be thinking about having a separate campaign for brand terms.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend placing brand terms into their own brand campaign.   This has a couple advantages.

1. Dedicated budget to ensure those who know your brand can find you.
2. Can customize ads to speak to brand shoppers.
3. Can add brand name to negative keywords in generic ad groups.